# Is there a way to create a VPN with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, vpn

I'm trying to create a VPN using javascript, HTML, and CSS. I'm currently just using an iframe, but it only gets around wifi proxies, and then some websites will refuse to connect with X-Frame-Options. I'm wondering if there's a way to create a *real* VPN with javascript. Thanks in advance!

**NEW UPDATE:** Is there another way I could get around 'system blocks'? I don't know what they're really called, but it's where you go on a website (usually on a Chromebook) and it says 'The person who set up this computer has chosen to block this site'. It doesn't work in an iframe, but is there another way with HTML, CSS, and javascript?

Comment: Unless you can route all traffic, then no. And in a browser (since you say HTML+CSS) you have no control of the traffic on the machine.

Answer (score 1):

A real VPN requires changing the way networking works on a computer.

This definitely isn't possible in browser-side JavaScript.

It would likely need custom extensions (probably written in C) before you could do it with Node.js or WSH.

Comment: Okay, thanks. Could you provide a link to something that could help me out with this?

Comment: @TyTy395 — No, I really can't. If you want a VPN, use some standard VPN software like Viscosity.

Comment: @TyTy395 Considering I spent an hour today looking at a VPN issue for a Linux subsystem, where there was an open bug from 2016, it seems like VPN isn't easy to just "do". Also, every single VPN client I've used for work has been bad. They range from total garbage to *only* "bad". And this is software that's made by a dedicated teams of experts, vetted by at least one team of experts. I've not used non-work related VPN but I suspect they are shinier with some other issues. I'm saying this because you're asking for resources and it seems like you're not ready to do it.

Comment: Okay. Is there at least a way around system blocks (see my new update)?

Comment: This is getting well outside the realm of "programming" and into "black hat security".

Answer (score 0):

You can use a privoxy chained to TOR

> /etc/privoxy/config

```
forward-socks5 127.0.0.1:9150
```

or just Tor with its HTTP server mode on.